# navigation spacing padding issue

Tags: css, navigation, padding

I am building a navigation where, despite my fiddling with padding, I cannot create equal distances between my sub menu's. It's a little hard to describe so I have created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kCXrX/

If someone has a sec could you let me know why, when you hover over a  element the distance between the line items are not the same -  there is a greater distance on the left than on the right

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. The demo looks fine to me.

Comment: I had to look at it for a few seconds myself to understand. go on a hover. if you look at how the orange hover is displayed, the distance from the right vertical line to the orange and the distance from the left vertical line to the orange is not the same. he wants that fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLzST/1/

Your HTML was invalid, ULs can't be direct children of ULs, so I've put your .submenu lists within LIs. One or two style tweaks, too.

Comment: thanks for the info - I'll know going for future about this rule

Answer (score 1):

in ul.subnav change your padding to this:`padding: 0 5px 10px 1px;`

if you did a ctrl-a on your table, you will see your `border-right` line actually has what seems to be a 3 pixel padding automatically added to itself. If you take that padding into account your code actually works fine. 
in any case heres the new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kCXrX/5/

Answer (score 0):

I've added `ul.subnav {border-left: solid 1px transparent;padding: 0 5px 10px 0;}` and now it looks beter to me.

Answer (score 0):

The extra padding appear just because you are using inline-block. try to remove this property (`display:inline-block`) and replace it with `float:left`.
now, it's time to tweak the .navigation so it force to containt the subnav (floating issue) by adding `overflow:hidden;`.
i have edit your fiddle, take a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/kCXrX/

Answer (score 0):

if orange hover left & right white spacing difference is the issue, check following code.

```
     ul.subnav {
         border-right: solid 1px;
         display: inline-block;
         height: 80px;
         padding: 0 5px 10px 1px;
         vertical-align: top;
         width: 116px;
     }
```